# Spring Boot Put payload with gzip compressed is getting truncated after upgrade to 3.2.0 from 3.1.9

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

put calls to an api are failing with gzipped data being truncated on uncompressing. The same api works fine with Spring Boot 3.1.9. After upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2.0 I observed that the data after uncompressing is truncated. Not able to identify the exact issue although it works fine with unzipped data. I suspected it to be tomcat issue so tried using the same version that gets bundled with SB 3.1.19 i.e. Tomcat 10.1.19 along with upgraded Spring Boot 3.2.0.

No Luck, Any pointer please share.

I am attaching the git repo url of the sample Spring Boot project along with test class that can be used reproduce the issue.

https://github.com/manjunathkadrolli/gzipissue

Comment: Have you tried the latest 3.2.3 which has some fixes in place for arrays and buffers.

Comment: The problem (or issue) is the `Content-Length` header. That has been set to 125. This is the value for the gzipped content. After unzipping it it is larger (218). However when the request body is read it will read only as many as needed (the content length). To fix this override all the `getHeader` and `getContentLength` options in the request wrapper to return the length of the `byte[]`.

Comment: Yes i had tried 3.2.3 also the latest 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There have been changes in Spring, especially when retrieving response bodies, to honour the `Content-Length` header. For a discussion see [this Github Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32162).

In short your request wrapper should also update the content-length and intercept the calls to all those headers, content length methods to return the proper size.

I took the liberty to strip and split your filter (as it is doing too much).

```java
package com.demo.gzipissue.config;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ReadListener;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Component
@Order(0)
public class GzipFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    var requestToUse = request;
    if (request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING) != null
        && request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING).contains("gzip")) {
      logger.debug("Recieved Content-Encoding:Gzip so will decompress the request.");
      requestToUse = new GzippedInputStreamWrapper(request);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(requestToUse, response);
  }

}

/**
 * Wrapper class that detects if the request is gzipped and ungzipps it.
 */
final class GzippedInputStreamWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

  /**
   * Serialized bytes array that is a result of unzipping gzipped body.
   */
  private final byte[] bytes;

  /**
   * Constructs a request object wrapping the given request. In case if
   * Content-Encoding contains "gzip" we wrap the input stream into byte array to
   * original input stream has nothing in it but hew wrapped input stream always
   * returns reproducible ungzipped input stream.
   *
   * @param request request which input stream will be wrapped.
   * @throws java.io.IOException when input stream reqtieval failed.
   */
  public GzippedInputStreamWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    var bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var in = new GZIPInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    in.transferTo(bos);
    bytes = bos.toByteArray();
  }

  /**
   * @return reproduceable input stream that is either equal to initial servlet
   * input stream(if it was not zipped) or returns unzipped input stream.
   */
  @Override
  public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
    final ByteArrayInputStream sourceStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    return new ServletInputStream() {
      public int read() {
        return sourceStream.read();
      }

      public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        sourceStream.close();
      }

      //@Override
      public boolean isFinished() {
        return false;
      }

      //@Override
      public boolean isReady() {
        return false;
      }

      //@Override
      public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public int getContentLength() {
    return bytes.length;
  }

  @Override
  public long getContentLengthLong() {
    return bytes.length;
  }

  @Override
  public String getHeader(String name) {
    if (HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
      return String.valueOf(bytes.length);
    }
    return super.getHeader(name);
  }

  @Override
  public int getIntHeader(String name) {
    if (HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
      return bytes.length;
    }
    return super.getIntHeader(name);
  }

  @Override
  public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
    if (HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
      return Collections.enumeration(Collections.singleton(getHeader(name)));
    }
    return super.getHeaders(name);
  }
}
```

For your original filter, you don't need the character-encoding stuff (Spring Boot already registers the `CharacterEncodingFilter` for that). Next to that Spring (and Spring Security) already have CORS support build in, I would suggest to use that.

Finally while this `GzipFilter` might work I would suggest using an out-of-the-box one that has proven itself in the field instead of writing your own.

Comment: Thanks a ton the setting of content length fixed the issue.